EasyRandom to honour initializer block
When I use org.jeasy.random.Easyrandom to generate a random instance of my class, it does not execute the code inside the init block.
My kotlin data class looks like this:
data class Leeftijd(
        val operator: LeeftijdOperator,
        val leeftijd: Int? = null,
        val leeftijdMin: Int? = null,
        val leeftijdMax: Int? = null
) {
    enum class LeeftijdOperator {
        IS_GELIJK_AAN, JONGER_DAN, OUDER_DAN, TUSSEN
    }

    init {
        when (operator) {
            IS_GELIJK_AAN, JONGER_DAN, OUDER_DAN -> {
                requireNotNull(leeftijd)
                require(leeftijdMin == null)
                require(leeftijdMax == null)
            }

            TUSSEN_LEEFTIJDEN -> {
                require(leeftijd == null)
                require(requireNotNull(leeftijdMin) <= requireNotNull(leeftijdMax))
            }
        }
    }
}

If I call EasyRandom().nextObject(Filter::class.java) it generates an instance where all fields are not null. But according to the init block, at least one of the fields should always be null.
Is there some way that I can tell EasyRandom it must at least call this init block? So I would be obliged to configure EasyRandom properly to instantiate my data class.

This can't be done using EasyRandom. See the documentation:

Easy Random is designed to generate random Java Beans. By definition, A Java Bean should provide a default constructor. If the target type does not provide a default constructor, Easy Random will still try to generate a random instance of it, but this is not guaranteed to work in all cases. In fact, Easy Random will fall back to objenesis for object creation (this can be overridden by providing a custom ObjectFactory instead of the default ObjenesisObjectFactory) which by-passes any constructor.

Your Kotlin data class is not a Java Bean. It has a non-default (i.e. no-arg) constructor, and has an init block which is part of the constructor as far as the JVM is concerned. EasyRandom creates the data class by simply setting the properties' backing fields to random values.
What you can do instead is create random instances by calling the constructor with random parameters.

OK thanks. I will have to look for something else then.

@Marc what are you using EasyRandom for? Is it for unit tests? If so, which framework are you using? If you're using Kotest, you can use its Property-based Testing features. If you're using JUnit 5, you can use jqwik.
